# lose focus() on input

Tags: javascript, html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

    <head>
        <title></title>
        <script type="text/javascript">

            function fiction()
            {
                shohai.javat.focus();
            }

        </script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <form  name="shohai">
            <input type="text" name="javat" placeholder="this is the text" >
            <br>
            <br>
            <input type="text" name="kamel" placeholder="this is the text 2" onblur="fiction2()">
            <br>
            <br>
            <button onclick="fiction()">Aceptar</button>    
        </form>

    </body>

</html>
```

thank you for answer me.
im traying to focus the javat input, it works but instantly loose his position. Why?
i searched in the web whit bad luck.

Comment: Its not clear on what you are trying to achieve, nevermind the fact that fiction2() is not defined.   focus() and blur() are DOM functions that highlight a specific html element.. best to check out this example http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_html_blur

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it seems to me that when you press the "Aceptar" button, the input does focus, but the form also submits, effectively reloading the page, and giving the impression that the focus is lost. This is because a `<button>` tag without any `type` attribute will default to `submit`. So, simply add a `type="button"` to the tag, so it is `<button type="button">`.

The full code with that change:

```
<form  name="shohai">
    <input type="text" name="javat" placeholder="this is the text" >
    <br>
    <br>
    <input type="text" name="kamel" placeholder="this is the text 2" onblur="fiction2()">
    <br>
    <br>
    <button type="button" onclick="fiction()">Aceptar</button>
</form>
```

And like other users said, it is not very clear what you want to do. Do you want "Aceptar" to... submit the form or just focus the input? You can't submit and focus at the same time (WELL, you can, but submitting a form reloads the whole page). And it'd also be a better idea to identify your elements via DOM methods, I didn't even know you could just do `shohai.javat`, to be honest.

Comment: thank you Leonarth im just learn it JS can you recommend me a book please.

Comment: Well, I have never read a JavaScript book, so I couldn't recommend one, but just browsing through the net is how you can learn the basic stuff. I really do like MDN's documentation on JavaScript, though. You can check that out in here: https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript . That particular link is in Spanish, I think you speak Spanish. (I do too! It is my native language). You should also read about HTML standards and best (JS and HTML) practices.